# Laravel Pagination with hydrated Model collection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 application which interacts with a database that has a pretty free-form schema. I have one particularly gnarly query that has not yet been converted into Eloquent syntax, instead we are stuck with `hydrateRaw` for the time being:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
...

class MyModel extends Model
{
    /** 
     * Do some crazy stuff to get a MyModel Collect
     *
     * @params so many
     * @return Collection
     */
    public static function getModels($param1, $param2, $param3, $limit)
    {   
        return static::hydrateRaw("SELECT table1.id, table2.name, table3.date from...", [$param1, $param2, $param3, $limit]);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have tried a number of different methods to shoehorn this collection into a `LengthAwarePaginator`, with partial success.

If I have this in the Controller:

```
$models = MyModel::getModels(1,2,3,1000);
$paginated = new LengthAwarePaginator($models, $models->count(), 12, 2);
```

And have a view like:

```
@foreach ($paginated as $model)
    {{ $model->name }}
@endforech
```

I get the whole collection (no pagination), although methods like `currentPage()` work correctly.

[The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) cryptically hint at using `array_slice` however I'm not sure what to do with it. If I call `$models->toArray()` I may as well have not hydrated the models (which is a nuisance because I was hoping to cache as much as possible).

I've jury rigged a solution that I've posted below, but I would really like to know if I can get pagination to just work because I'm going to run into this situation a few more times, would like to keep as much logic out of the views as possible, and just have a feeling a little tweak could get this to work.

Comment: Please correct me if I've misunderstood your question, but in the view, you want to iterate the `$paginated` object, not the whole collection that is `$models`. Then you should get paginated results and by calling `$models->links()` you render the pagination controls.

Comment: That was a typo! I am interating over $paginated and getting the entire, unpaginated collection as results.

Comment: I tested your code with a relatively simple raw query (take several columns from one table and join two others on it) and it worked for me, your problem might be related to the complex query you're running.

Comment: Did you use hydrateRaw? The query produces the expected results, with the code I posted below it even paginates correctly, is there something else that could go wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did use `hydrateRaw` but maybe it only worked for me because the schema and resulting data weren't that complicated, unfortunately I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution involves the Model and Controller setup shown above, then in the view I have:

```
@foreach ($paginated->forPage($paginated->currentPage(), $paginated->perPage()) as $model)
    {{ $model->name }}
@endforeach
```

I get the right model instances, but the docs don't show pagination working like that, so I feel like there is room for improvement.